# Create headline row in LibreOffice Calc's ODS document

Tags: sorting, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, ods

Can I create headline row in LibreOffice Calc's ODS document, which is not joining in data sorting procedure, when I trying to sort table's data (by selected column's data)?

For example:

1. I have following table:

```
----------------
|Col1|Col2|Col3|
----------------
|A   |.   |0   |
----------------
|C   |,   |2   |
----------------
|B   |!   |1   |
----------------
```

2. When I'm trying to sort this table's data (from A to Z) by column number 3, my headline rown should not moves in footer.

Comment: If you open the "Sort" dialogue via the menu, there is an option "Range contains column/row labels" you can switch on. -- However, this is not a programming question, is it?

Comment: @busybee, thanks you for your answer, but I can't done this task via sorting dialogue window... Sorry, that is not a programming question.